# how to render array of responsejson in flatlist?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am Beginner in React-Native explain Me Please
my response.json() is

```
{
"1".{name:bob,class:12},
2".{name:anax,class:123}
}
```

How to render this into Flatlist

Comment: This may help you - https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6

Comment: Is it a JSON? not look like a json

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
<FLatList 
 data={Object.keys(res)}// res is your resonse object
 ...
 renderItem={({ item, index }) => 
 //to access data of your res use this res[item]
   <Text>res[item].name</Text>
 }
/>
```

Comment: "Thanks",   I pushed the responseJson to temp array .